# The multipart identifier couldn't be bound

Tags: python, sql, парсер

Я пишу парсер сайта и мне надо, чтобы все ссылки скидывались в базу данных. Вот что у меня получается

```
sitename = 'ripple.html'
with open (sitename) as fp: 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
finder = soup.find_all('a' , text =True)
href = ''
text = ''
def linkerfind(link):
    href = '\''+link.get('href')+'\'' 
    text = '\'' + link.text + '\''
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO dbo.ParsedSites (SiteName,href,text)VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""%(sitename,href,text))
    cursor.commit()
    return cursor


for link in finder :
    linkerfind(link)
```

Коннект к БД я пропустил он работает.Некоторую часть кода тоже, она тоже работает. По итогу мне выдает ошибку:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "ripple.html" could not be bound. (4104) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Я пробовал ставить кавычки возле `ripple`. Все столбцы в БД есть. Нужна помощь.